# `react-router` warning solution and passing root props to sub routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Sometime I was sawing the well known warning, `browser.js:49 Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored` and I found two trend issues that friends discussed about this issue and the solution is `const` routes components and putting them inside `Router` component.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2704

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/179

Just like below:

**you will see warning with this code:**

```
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory} createElement={this.createElement}>
        <Route component={App}>
          <Route path="/" component={MainPage}/>
          <Route path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
          <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsPage}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

**but you won't see warning with this code:**

```
const routes = (
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainPage}/>
    <Route path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
    <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsPage}/>
  </Route>
);

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory} createElement={this.createElement}>
        {routes}
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

This is OK, awesome solution to vanish [react-router] warning, and for `Root Component` changing `state` the `routes` was static and you won't see any warnings. ***BUT*** my issue is: I pass `Root Component` props to each `Route` and I can not do the above solution  ,
I must put App `Route` inside Router so with this method absolutely this is not solution method and I will saw the known warning again, see my router code:

```
export default class AppRoutes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path="/" {...this.props} component={App}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home}  {...this.props}/>
                    <Route path="/transaction" component={Transaction} {...this.props}/>
                    <Route path="/users-management" component={UsersManagement} {...this.props}/>
                    <Route path="/issues" component={Issues} {...this.props}/>
                    <Route path='/not-found' component={NotFound}/>
                    <Route path='/settlement-management' component={SettlementManagement} {...this.props}/>
                    <Route path='/categories-management' component={CategoriesManagement} {...this.props}/>
                    <Route path='/gifts-management' component={GiftsManagement} {...this.props}/>
                    <Redirect from='/*' to='/not-found'/>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

And the `Root Component` render code is:

```
render(){
    return(
        <AppRoutes {...this}/>
    );
}
```

I passed this as a props to `AppRoutes` component and I need to pass inherited `this.props` to sub `Route`s and use them. how I could won't see warning and pass props to any `Route`s?

One of my solution is that, I write all `Route`s as static and call `Root Component` `props` directly inside each component, but how? I don't know how I can call and keep `props` of `Root Component` inside the component that need to have `props` of `Root Component` as the component is not direct `Root Component` children?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render` route prop instead of `component` to pass props to your components :

```
<Route path="/transaction" render={() => <Transaction {...this.props} />} />
```

Edit : Or this to also pass route props :

```
<Route path="/transaction" render={(routeProps) => <Transaction parentProps={this.props} {...routeProps}  />} />
```

(I think it's better to pass individual custom parent props to not enter in conflict with routeProps)

Comment: I wrote like you, `<Route path="/transaction" render={() => <Transaction {...this.props}/>}/>` , but it didn't work. Even didn't render `Transaction` like before.

Comment: Also this is not my solution, because when I migrate `<Route path="/" {...this.props} component={App}>` and its children to a `const` variable outside of class, then there is no different between your code style and mine. out side of class `this` has no meaning.

Comment: This is not to create a const outside the class, this is to pass props to your component instead of passing them to the route (the warning tells you that the new props you pass to the routes are ignored)

Comment: this does not help me, I have and other solution, how I can use `Root Component` props directly inside other Components?